# How to close a Thread properly in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a method that i am calling inside the Thread.Here is the Method..

```
 private System.Threading.Thread _thread;
 private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

 private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        { 
              //Business logic
        }
    }
```

and Now here i am starting the Thread..

```
 _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
 _thread.Start();
```

Now as per my requirement i want to close and restart the Thread..For Closing and restarting i am trying this code..

```
  _shutdownEvent.Set();  // trigger the thread to stop
  _thread.Join();
```

but i think this is not the right way to close the Thread and restart it again..

Please help me to close and restart the Thread in my case.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov .Net4.0

Comment: @shubhamHegdey in that case you might consider using TPL

Comment: There are other approaches, but I don't really see a problem with the way you're doing it.

Comment: Are you trying to cancel ongoing work and restart it? The only _iffy_ thing going on here is the low level threading code but it seems functionally sound.

Comment: ManualResetEvent should be used for synchronizing 2 threads that needs  to cooperate on the same operation

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you to look into the [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx), which enables fine-grained control over its execution and [supports a cancellation mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) via the `CancellationToken` structure:

Here's an example:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
        // Were we already canceled?
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        bool moreToDo = true;
        while (moreToDo)
        {
            // Poll on this property if you have to do 
            // other cleanup before throwing. 
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Clean up here, then...
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

        }
    }, tokenSource.Token); // Pass same token to StartNew.

tokenSource.Cancel();
```

Regarding "restarting the thread", you cannot restart a given `Task`. What you can do is see that it was canceled (A task contains a `Status` property which will turn into `Canceled` once you cancel) and if so, execute a new task.

Answer (score 3):

You should really try to avoid managing threads yourself, and let the CLR do that for you. Creating threads is an expensive error prone activity best left alone.

The FCL provides types that you can use to manage threads. Take a look at [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.100).aspx) which will execute some code given in a callback. This works well in situations where you just want to say "Go do something" and you don't care when/if it completes, and it has no return value. If you want to see the return value, and know when something is completed, use [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.100).aspx).

I highly recommend [CLR via C#](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/CLR_Via_C.html?id=QMdCf_mm55cC&redir_esc=y) by Jeffrey Richer. It has an excellent section on threading and different ways of using them in your .Net code.

Answer (score 2):

erm, try something modern.

```
private Task DoWork(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // ... It would be nice if you could await something here.
    }

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

then, just signal the `CancellationToken`,

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    await Task.WhenAny(
        DoWork(cts.Token),
        SomeOtherWork())

    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you're currently waiting for the thread to finish looks fine - Threads die when they run out of code, and `Join` ensures that it has finished.

You cannot restart a thread though, you'll have to create a new one.

I do agree with the other answers you may want to look into the new technologies available, they allow for more readable code.